# Stack Exchange code block line numbers userscript

Tags: script, design, style

### Screenshot

> [image: Dark mode code block with prefixed line numbers]
> [image: Light mode code block with prefixed line numbers]

### About

I've always wanted to have line numbers prefixed in code blocks on questions / answers.
This userscript takes the code-blocks on the page, and inserts line numbers.

It will look at the length of the code block to determine the required additional padding, so a short code-block wouldn't have too much whitespace to allow for 3-digit line numbers.

#### Download

**[Download Link](https://github.com/Cerbrus/userscripts/raw/master/stack-exchange-line-numbers.cerbrus.user.js)**

If you don't have a userscript client, you'll need one. [TamperMonkey](https://tampermonkey.net) for Chrome or [GreaseMonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/) for FireFox are good options.

### Contact

The best way is to leave a [Github Issue](https://github.com/Cerbrus/userscripts/issues) for feature reqs, issues, and anything related to the userscript.

### Code

The code is on [Github](https://github.com/Cerbrus/userscripts/tree/master/)

Comment: You won't need to manually calculate the width of the line numbers element if you are [using display: flex](https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts/blob/master/CodeLineNumbers.user.js)

Answer (score 2):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

Doesn't work on pages without any code highlighting because it waits for `.hljs`, and the code block does not have the class `.s-code-block`.

`waitForKeyElements('.hljs', addLineNumbers, false);`

Example question/page: https://stackoverflow.com/q/76688458

Comment: Good point! The next version looks for `pre` elements, which also means the line numbers don't need to wait for hljs to run :D Fixed in 1.2.

Answer (score 2):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) ?

The regex counting the number of lines should target the code element inside the pre element, and not the pre (parent) element itself.

Answer (score 2):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

The line numbers are selectable from the page. Suggested to make them unselectable by adding `user-select: none;` on top of `pointer-events: none;`